# Using list comprehensions to make a funcion more pythonic

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I'm doing some [Google Python Class](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/exercises/basic) exercises and I'm trying to find a pythonic solution to the following problem.

> D. Given a list of numbers, return a list where all adjacent ==
>   elements have been reduced to a single element, so [1, 2, 2, 3]
>   returns [1, 2, 3]. You may create a new list or modify the passed in
>   list.

My try, which is working perfectly is the following:

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
  result = []
  for num in nums:
    if len(result) == 0 or num != result[-1]:
      result.append(num)
  return result
```

For example, with `remove_adjacent([2, 2, 3, 3, 3])` the output is `[2, 3]`. Everything's ok.

I'm trying to use list comprehensions in order to archieve this in a more *pythonic* way, so my try is the following:

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):  
  result = []
  result = [num for num in nums if (len(result)==0 or num!=result[-1])]
  return result
```

This, with the same input `[2, 2, 3, 3, 3]`, the output is `[2, 2, 3, 3, 3]` (the same). Meeeh! Wrong.

What I'm doing wrong with the list comprehensions? Am I trying to do something which is impossible to do with list comprehensions? I know it's a bit weird to initialize the list (`result = []`), so maybe it's not posible to do it using list comprehensions in this case.

Comment: just as an fyi `list(set([2, 2, 3, 3, 3]))` will return `[2, 3]`.  However, this only reduces the list to a unique set of values.  It doesn't necessarily remove adjacent duplicates.

Comment: where did you get the `res` varaiable

Comment: also, `res` should be `result`

Comment: @VigneshKalai It's `result` , not `res`. My mistake copying the code.

Comment: @Borja then you will get the same number only since len(result) will be equal to 0 till the list comprehension ends

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Am I trying to do something which is impossible to do with list comprehensions?

Yep. A list comprehension can't refer to itself by name, because the variable doesn't get bound at all until the comprehension is completely done evaluating. That's why you get a `NameError` if you don't have `result = []` in your second code block.

If it's not cheating to use standard modules, consider using `groupby` to group together similar values in your list:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> seq = [1, 2, 2, 3]
>>> [k for k,v in itertools.groupby(seq)]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> seq = [2,2,3,3,3]
>>> [k for k,v in itertools.groupby(seq)]
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of learning, I'd suggest using core `reduce` function:

```
def remove_adjacent(lst):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x+[y] if not x or x[-1] != y else x, lst, [])
```